# How are the android apps like talking carl and talking tom cat developed?

Tags: android

I'd like to write an app like talking carl / talking tom cat but was wondering how they are developed?

- Are they animated on the fly using 3d?  The general actions dont seem to be, they look like a series of movies being played?
- If this is the case, how is the movement of the mouth animation done?

Answer (score 5):

I can't give an authoritative answer, but it seems to be composed of pre-rendered 3d images.
The mouth animation is done simply by swapping images. You will notice that the cat is always in the same position when it talks.